# Maintaining font style/formatting into a form that doesn't support html/markdown

Tags: html, text, format, markdown

I have looked into the previous postings to do with this area but haven't found any relevant answers as perhaps I am asking the wrong question.

On the popular design site Dribbble, there seem to be interesting formatting changes in profile names that break from the conventions of the site's styling.

Alot of people have been adding special characters (ΔδΓ etc.) that can be achieved by pasting into their profile form and saving changes, yet some users have somehow managed to enter formatted versions of their name, despite the profile form not supporting HTML or Markdown. You can see an example in the images below.

[An example of copying the font to Google with maintained formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA0eJ.jpg)

[When opening in inspector, it also shows the formatted type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeT2e.png)

How could this be done in a simple text input form that doesn't support HTML/Markdown?

Comment: the form needs to be installed on your system, or imported in the website. what your'e seeing on your developers console is due to the face that the same font (Times New Roman) happens to be installed on your system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are almost certainly [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters, just like these characters that you reference in your question: `ΔδΓ`.

For example, Unicode's [mathematical alphanumeric symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf) section includes symbols that look like the ones in your screenshot. Since these are separate Unicode characters there is no need for additional formatting.

Users will need to have a font that supports those characters installed locally to view them.